# How to render or update list in vue js if in array value changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my vue code:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        searchedLocation:'',
        loctionsResults:[]
    },
    watch:{
        searchedLocation:function(){
            this.getLocations();
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getLocations: _.debounce(function(){
            // Make a request to get list of locations
            axios.get('/getLocations/'+ this.searchedLocation)
              .then(function (response) {
                //console.log(response.data);
                this.loctionsResults = response.data;
                console.log(this.loctionsResults);
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });

        },500)

        },

});
```

my Html :

```
<label for="location">Search by location</label>
<input type="text" name="location"  v-model='searchedLocation'>
<ul>
    <li v-for = "item in loctionsResults">
    @{{item.location}}
   </li>


</ul>
```

What I want?:
when i type something in input it will send a request using axios and then getting some result. But when trying to render that result it does not show any list.
How i can make that happen?

Comment: might need `Vue.set` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: use `app.loctionsResults = response.data`

Comment: @talkhabi Thank you very much. it worked. but why `this` not worked?

Comment: @RakeshKohali have you tried using a fat arrow function? `() => {}`

Comment: I am new to Vue and javascript. But i must learn arrow functions. Thank you very much.

Comment: Because `this` dose not refers to `Vue` instance, its inside a function @rakesh-kohali

Comment: @talkhabi. Thanks i understood.